# Integrating firebase authentication with Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, next.js

I'm having trouble understanding this Next.js example of using firebase with a [serverless app](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/master/examples/with-firebase-authentication-serverless).

I've successfully managed to implement the authentication phase and added Google as an Authentication provider. What I'm stumbling at is that when loading my index page immediately after the the login, the server does not seem to have access to the `AuthUser` and `AuthUserInfo` objects that the Next team have created to share the authentication information.

However, if I refresh the page, the information becomes available. This is confusing me.
Below I've shared my `index.js` and the code for the `AuthUser` and the `AuthUserInfo` Components.

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { get } from 'lodash/object'
import Link from 'next/link'
import Router from 'next/router'
import withAuthUser from '../utils/pageWrappers/withAuthUser'
import withAuthUserInfo from '../utils/pageWrappers/withAuthUserInfo'
import logout from '../utils/auth/logout'

const Index = props => {
  const { AuthUserInfo, data } = props
  const AuthUser = get(AuthUserInfo, 'AuthUser', null)
  const { favoriteFood } = data
  // [OP's COMMENT]: This logs the AuthUser object correctly even immediately after the login
  console.log(AuthUser)

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Hi there!</p>
      {!AuthUser ? (
        <p>
          You are not signed in.{' '}
          <Link href={'/auth'}>
            <a>Sign in</a>
          </Link>
        </p>
      ) : (
        <div>
          <p>You're signed in. Email: {AuthUser.email}</p>
          <p
            style={{
              display: 'inlinelock',
              color: 'blue',
              textDecoration: 'underline',
              cursor: 'pointer',
            }}
            onClick={async () => {
              try {
                await logout()
                Router.push('/auth')
              } catch (e) {
                console.error(e)
              }
            }}
          >
            Log out
          </p>
        </div>
      )}
      <div>
        <Link href={'/example'}>
          <a>Another example page</a>
        </Link>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div>Your favorite food is {favoriteFood}.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

// Just an example.
const mockFetchData = async userId => ({
  user: {
    ...(userId && {
      id: userId,
    }),
  },
  favoriteFood: 'pizza',
})

Index.getInitialProps = async ctx => {
  // Get the AuthUserInfo object. This is set in `withAuthUser.js`.
  // The AuthUserInfo object is available on both the server and client.
  const AuthUserInfo = get(ctx, 'myCustomData.AuthUserInfo', null)
  const AuthUser = get(AuthUserInfo, 'AuthUser', null)

  // You can also get the token (e.g., to authorize a request when fetching data)
  const AuthUserToken = get(AuthUserInfo, 'token', null)
  // [OP's COMMENT]: In the initial login this returns null, but after refreshing while logged in it returns the infomation correctly correctly
  console.log(AuthUser)

  // You can fetch data here.
  const data = await mockFetchData(get(AuthUser, 'id'))

  return {
    data,
  }
}

Index.displayName = 'Index'

Index.propTypes = {
  AuthUserInfo: PropTypes.shape({
    AuthUser: PropTypes.shape({
      id: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      email: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      emailVerified: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    }),
    token: PropTypes.string,
  }),
  data: PropTypes.shape({
    user: PropTypes.shape({
      id: PropTypes.string,
    }).isRequired,
    favoriteFood: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  }).isRequired,
}

Index.defaultProps = {
  AuthUserInfo: null,
}

// Use `withAuthUser` to get the authed user server-side, which
// disables static rendering.
// Use `withAuthUserInfo` to include the authed user as a prop
// to your component.
export default withAuthUser(withAuthUserInfo(Index))
```

`withAuthUser.js`

```
/* eslint react/jsx-props-no-spreading: 0 */

import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { get, set } from 'lodash/object'
import { AuthUserInfoContext, useFirebaseAuth } from '../auth/hooks'
import { createAuthUser, createAuthUserInfo } from '../auth/user'

// Gets the authenticated user from the Firebase JS SDK, when client-side,
// or from the request object, when server-side. Add the AuthUserInfo to
// context.
export default ComposedComponent => {
  const WithAuthUserComp = props => {
    const { AuthUserInfo, ...otherProps } = props

    // We'll use the authed user from client-side auth (Firebase JS SDK)
    // when available. On the server side, we'll use the authed user from
    // the session. This allows us to server-render while also using Firebase's
    // client-side auth functionality.
    const { user: firebaseUser } = useFirebaseAuth()
    const AuthUserFromClient = createAuthUser(firebaseUser)
    const { AuthUser: AuthUserFromSession, token } = AuthUserInfo
    const AuthUser = AuthUserFromClient || AuthUserFromSession || null

    return (
      <AuthUserInfoContext.Provider value={{ AuthUser, token }}>
        <ComposedComponent {...otherProps} />
      </AuthUserInfoContext.Provider>
    )
  }

  WithAuthUserComp.getInitialProps = async ctx => {
    const { req, res } = ctx

    // Get the AuthUserInfo object.
    let AuthUserInfo
    if (typeof window === 'undefined') {
      // If server-side, get AuthUserInfo from the session in the request.
      // Don't include server middleware in the client JS bundle. See:
      // https://arunoda.me/blog/ssr-and-server-only-modules
      const { addSession } = require('../middleware/cookieSession')
      addSession(req, res)
      AuthUserInfo = createAuthUserInfo({
        firebaseUser: get(req, 'session.decodedToken', null),
        token: get(req, 'session.token', null),
      })
    } else {
      // If client-side, get AuthUserInfo from stored data. We store it
      // in _document.js. See:
      // https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/2252#issuecomment-353992669
      try {
        const jsonData = JSON.parse(
          window.document.getElementById('__MY_AUTH_USER_INFO').textContent
        )
        if (jsonData) {
          AuthUserInfo = jsonData
        } else {
          // Use the default (unauthed) user info if there's no data.
          AuthUserInfo = createAuthUserInfo()
        }
      } catch (e) {
        // If there's some error, use the default (unauthed) user info.
        AuthUserInfo = createAuthUserInfo()
      }
    }

    // Explicitly add the user to a custom prop in the getInitialProps
    // context for ease of use in child components.
    set(ctx, 'myCustomData.AuthUserInfo', AuthUserInfo)

    // Evaluate the composed component's getInitialProps().
    let composedInitialProps = {}
    if (ComposedComponent.getInitialProps) {
      composedInitialProps = await ComposedComponent.getInitialProps(ctx)
    }

    return {
      ...composedInitialProps,
      AuthUserInfo,
    }
  }

  WithAuthUserComp.displayName = `WithAuthUser(${ComposedComponent.displayName})`

  WithAuthUserComp.propTypes = {
    AuthUserInfo: PropTypes.shape({
      AuthUser: PropTypes.shape({
        id: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
        email: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
        emailVerified: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
      }),
      token: PropTypes.string,
    }).isRequired,
  }

  WithAuthUserComp.defaultProps = {}

  return WithAuthUserComp
}
```

`withAuthUserInfo.js`

```
/* eslint react/jsx-props-no-spreading: 0 */

import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { get } from 'lodash/object'
import { AuthUserInfoContext } from '../auth/hooks'

// Provides an AuthUserInfo prop to the composed component.
export default ComposedComponent => {
  const WithAuthUserInfoComp = props => {
    const { AuthUserInfo: AuthUserInfoFromSession, ...otherProps } = props
    return (
      <AuthUserInfoContext.Consumer>
        {AuthUserInfo => (
          <ComposedComponent
            {...otherProps}
            AuthUserInfo={AuthUserInfo || AuthUserInfoFromSession}
          />
        )}
      </AuthUserInfoContext.Consumer>
    )
  }

  WithAuthUserInfoComp.getInitialProps = async ctx => {
    const AuthUserInfo = get(ctx, 'myCustomData.AuthUserInfo', null)

    // Evaluate the composed component's getInitialProps().
    let composedInitialProps = {}
    if (ComposedComponent.getInitialProps) {
      composedInitialProps = await ComposedComponent.getInitialProps(ctx)
    }

    return {
      ...composedInitialProps,
      AuthUserInfo,
    }
  }

  WithAuthUserInfoComp.displayName = `WithAuthUserInfo(${ComposedComponent.displayName})`

  WithAuthUserInfoComp.propTypes = {
    AuthUserInfo: PropTypes.shape({
      AuthUser: PropTypes.shape({
        id: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
        email: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
        emailVerified: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
      }),
      token: PropTypes.string,
    }),
  }

  WithAuthUserInfoComp.defaultProps = {}

  return WithAuthUserInfoComp
}
```

I'm pretty sure that there's something going on with server side rendering and (possibly with promises) that I'm not understanding. I could push the data fetching to the client side if I have to, but I'd like to understand why this isn't working. Should I perhaps be forcing a refresh immediately after the login? The Next team themselves have added the following snippet to the `getInitialProps` method in `index.js`

```
  // You can also get the token (e.g., to authorize a request when fetching data)
  const AuthUserToken = get(AuthUserInfo, 'token', null)
```

So I'm guessing its intended to work immediately after a login as well.

Comment: did you ever find an answer to this?

Comment: No. Instead Next changed their firebase auth example: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-firebase-authentication. The new exmaple works well for me, though it might not work with Server Sider Rendering.